# AWS Throttling exceptions on DescribeAutoScalingInstances and SetInstanceProtection

Tags: amazon-web-services, throttling

I'm trying to set instance protection on autoscaling dynamically, but im getting these exceptions:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (Throttling) when calling the DescribeAutoScalingInstances operation (reached max retries: 4): Rate exceeded
```

and

```
ClientError: An error occurred (Throttling) when calling the SetInstanceProtection operation (reached max retries: 4): Rate exceeded
```

looked everywhere for throttle limits and token bucket size info on these, but didn't find anything. where can I find info about these limits of mine?

Answer (score 1):

All AWS APIs will throw throttling errors when called too often. While some of these APIs have a hard limit for invocations (e.g. the [PutMetricData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_limits.html) endpoint for CloudWatch), most of them don't and how often you can call them without getting throttling errors varies based on the utilization of AWS internal services. So if you have no luck finding information about the limit it's probably such a dynamic one.